# Unable to Access This in a Field Initializer to Read 'property"

Tags: flutter, authentication, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, bloc

I am trying to authenticate a user using bloc pattern and repository. I have also used `GetIt` to inject some of my dependencies like below:

```
final getItInstance = GetIt.I;

Future init(){
   getItInstance.registerLazySingleton<APIClient>(() => APIClient());
   getItInstance.registerLazySingleton<UserRemoteDataSource>(
      () => UserRemoteDataSourceImpl(client: getItInstance()));
  // commented out previously,  getItInstance.registerLazySingleton<UserRepository>(
      () => UserRepositoryImpl(dataSource: getItInstance()));
}
```

and the implementations of the faulty `UserRepository` classes are:

```
abstract class UserRepository {
  Future<UserModel> loginUser(Map<String, dynamic> body);
  Future<UserModel> registerUser(Map<String, dynamic> body);
  Future<UserModel> getCurrentUser();
  Future<void> logOut();
}
```

The `UserRepositoryImpl` class is just a wrapper to implement the above methods and connect with the remote data source via http, so has been omitted. From the DI class, one can easily see the dependencies and dependents, I have omitted them for brevity's sake.

Now, in my `auth bloc`, I am trying to pass the `UserRepository and UserRepositoryImpl` to the bloc constructor, to facilitate the api call but I get this error:

```
lib/presentation/blocs/authentication/authentication_bloc.dart:18:42: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read '_repository'.
  : _repository = repository, assert(_repository != null),
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here's the bloc constructor:

```
class AuthenticationBloc
extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {

  final UserRepository _repository;
  AuthenticationBloc(UserRepositoryImpl repository)
  : assert(_repository != null), _repository = repository,
    super(AuthenticationStateInitial());

  ... other methods etc
 }
```

Please, what does this mean and how do I rectify it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have realized my mistake, in the constructor, instead of asserting the constructor params to be non null, I was checking for the field value of the repository. Here's the correction from:

```
final UserRepository _repository;
AuthenticationBloc(UserRepositoryImpl repository)
  : assert(**_repository** != null), _repository = repository, 
    super(AuthenticationStateInitial());
```

to:

```
final UserRepository _repository;
AuthenticationBloc(UserRepositoryImpl repository)
  : assert(**repository** != null), _repository = repository,
    super(AuthenticationStateInitial());
```

** signifies where the change was made in the two code blocks. Hope it can help someone too.